# I need the function to return true if the ajax result is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my code:

```
    function validateField(field, input) {

    if (field && input) { 

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax/verify"); ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'field' : field, 'input' : input},
            success: function(result) {
                var available = result.available;
                if (available == 1) {

                   // return true (for the entire function);
                }

            }
        });
    } 

    return false;


}
```

Comment: You have an anonymous callback, returning true will not help you. You need to set yourself up to handle AJAX properly.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous and it happens in the background. You need to bind a callback to the `success()` that does what you want.

Comment: Do you guys have an example how I could re-construct the function to make it work the way I need it to? Not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: You should wait for the response and continue from there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowadays the most correct to do that is to use [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
function validateField(field, input) {
    if (field && input) { 
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax/verify"); ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'field' : field, 'input' : input}
        }).pipe(function(result) {
            var available = result.available;
            return available == 1;
        });
    }

    return $.Deferred().resolve(false);
}

validateField('somefield', 'someinput')
    .done(function(result) {
        if (result) {
            alert('it is true');
        } else {
            alert('it is false');
        }
    });
```

And callback-based solution (I don't like it ;-):

```
function validateField(field, input, callback) {
    var cb = $.isFunction(callback) ? callback : $.noop;

    if (field && input) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax/verify"); ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'field' : field, 'input' : input},
            success: function(result) {
                var available = result.available;
                cb(available == 1);
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    cb(false);
}

validateField('somefield', 'someinput', function(result) {
    if (result) {
        alert('it is true');
    } else {
        alert('it is false');
    }
});
```

Comment: Whoa. Is this new jQuery magic? It looks really cool and powerful, even though I have zero idea what any of it means at first glance.

Comment: @Matchu: 1. Yep, deferreds is a preferrable way to process ajax results, since `success` callback is deprecated since jquery 1.8; 2. This is an amazing article about how to deal with it: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Comment: Why is this the most correct way? Isn't it simpler and cleaner to pass a callback to the `validateField`?

Comment: @user1600680: `success` callback is deprecated since jquery 1.8. And callbacks haven't been "clean" solution ever - they required a lot of work around them and lead to tangled and confusing logic. Just trust me that deferreds are sexy

Comment: Oh wow, they really deprecated the success callback? I didn't know that. Did they deprecate the other callbacks too so that we must use deferreds?

Comment: This certainly looks like a nice new feature to explore, thanks for sharing +1

Comment: @user1600680: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - ctrl+f using "deprecat". Finally `async: false` is deprecated!!!

Comment: @zerkms: holy cow, just finished reading that article. This is very, very cool ­— glad I stumbled into here. Thanks again.

Comment: @Matchu: yep, actually it *completely changed* the way I work with any asynchronous (or even just dependent) processes after I've read that article. PS: to be clear I've read it 2 or 3 times in a row to completely get the idea (at least `.pipe()` thing was a bit confusing at a first glance)

Comment: According to that document, the `.success()` method is deprecated, not the `success:` callback property.

Comment: @user1600680: isn't it the same thing?

Comment: The `success` property is still listed among the other `$.ajax` properties. It seems that the `jqXHR` object had a method for each callback type, and from what I can tell, it's the method versions that are deprecated.

Comment: @user1600680: actually I cannot think of how useful can be `jqXHR.complete()` and other methods. So, well, I'm totally confused :-S But anyway, deferreds are much nicer anyway :-)

Comment: @user1600680: regardless, deferreds are still much cooler ;) But if you can put together a callback-based solution, whatever works.

Comment: Just to compare - added callback based solution. Not to mention, that for ajax errors we need to pass another callback thus modify the function parameters and function's body. While with deferreds we wouldn't change it at all, but just add another `.fail()` handler.

Comment: thanks, I integrated this into my application and it worked right away.

Comment: Going back to user1600680's idea, a callback can be passed to validateField without necessarily using it as a success callback. You could simply replace `.pipe(...)` with `.done(callback)`. This still leverages the power of deferreds/promises and does not employ any deprecated techniques. It's a question of what's most appropriate in the context of the overall application.

Comment: And user1600680 is right, the jqXHR *methods* `.success()`, `.error()` and `.complete()` are deprecated from 1.8 (in favour of the standardized Deferred methods `.done(), .fail() and .always()`). The `$.ajax({...})` option equivalents remain legal. They are definitely *not* the same thing. That said, I agree that Deferreds are cool. I've been using them for a while now and have answered several questions here on SO on that basis.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: thanks for clarification. Haven't heard of `jqXHR` `.success()` and others :-S

Comment: @zerkms, you should have heard of them. The deprecation of `.success()` etc. is included in the page *you* linked to. Try following your own advice - ctrl+f using "deprecat" :)

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: yeah, I know it is deprecated. I haven't heard of that functions. I mean I've never used them, didn't even know they exist and cannot think of how useful they can be ;-)

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: yep ;-) So glad I could relocate here (from Russia o_O)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is to make the request synchronous (`async: false`) and toggle the value of a boolean variable in the outer scope within the success function. **This is not recommended, nor even supported as of jQuery 1.8.** Ajax is based on a callback pattern, triggering some function if some condition is met. It would be better to do whatever it is you do if valid, within the success function of the ajax callback.

```
function validateField(field, input, success) {
    var valid = false;

    if (field && input) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax/verify"); ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'field' : field, 'input' : input},
            success: function(result) {
                var available = result.available;
                if (available == 1) {

                   // return true (for the entire function);
                    valid = true;

                    // BETTER TO CALL doSomethingIfValid(); here
                }

            }
        });
    }

    return valid;
}​
```